# How to go from handlebars.js to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js

I had a project about a month ago that used `handlebars.js` for templates, and now we have to update it to use `react.js` instead. How would I approach that? This is one of the pages I'm in charge of changing.

Home page:

```
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-16 px-4 sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p
      class="text-3xl font-extrabold text-transparent sm:text-6xl bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-300 via-blue-500 to-purple-600">
      Geek Emporium</p>
    <p class="max-w-xl mt-5 mx-auto text-xl text-gray-500">Your one stop shop for all your nerdy needs!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<article class="post">
  <div class="bg-white">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-16 px-4 overflow-hidden sm:py-24 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-10 gap-x-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">

        {{#each posts as |post|}}

        {{> post-info-homepage post }}

        {{/each}}

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use react somewhat similar to template engine does. check this one => https://dev.to/saltyshiomix/express-react-as-a-view-template-engine-h37

Comment: When you say that you want to "update it to use react.js", do you mean that you want to use react as a server-side rendering tool? or do you want to change your application from being a MPA to a SPA? Changing from a MPA to a SPA is going to take a bit of time and effort. They are entirely different architectures, and are usually used to solve different kinds of problems. They aren't easily interchangeable.